# Converting Python 2.x function definition into Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function definition in a Python 2.x script which takes a
tuple as one of its arguments, but 2to3 has no answers nor any of
my searching on how to represent the same in Python 3.x

eg.

```
def blah(self, (string1, string2)):
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It's simple.

```
def blah(self, strings):
  string1, string2 = strings
  ...
```

Comment: hmmm ... I am not sure that will work for me. I guess I should elaborate, I thought I could make it simple.

I have code that defines the following:

def blah(self, (string1, string2)):
    return blah2('help', (string1, string2))

and 

def blah2(self, name, string1=None):
  ...

So if blah is only that 2 line def, how does your suggestion work in this context? (or am I missing the  point)

Sorry to not have elaborated the first time if this is now completely different scenario :(

Comment: The definition of `blah` changes to be `def blah(self, strings): return blah2('help', *strings)`